# Rails Devise roots, what's the difference between namespace and authenticated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In a Rails 3.2 app I have two user models set up using Devise: Admin and User.

I have an Admin-specific root page defined in my routes file.

```
namespace :admin do
    root :to => "pages#welcome"
end
```

I have also seen this written as

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => 'pages#welcome'
end
```

I have not been able to find a clear description of the difference between using `namespace` and `authenticated`, and what implications this may have for security.

I'd be very grateful if someone could enlighten me, or point me towards a clear description.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Namespace routes will always exist -- meaning you can always call
  /admin and it will route to pages#welcome
- Authenticated routes will only exist if the :user is logged in.

I use it to create a root_path that's a dashboard for a logged in user, but the marketing pages#welcome for non logged in:

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => 'profile#show'
end
root :to => 'pages#welcome'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to devise doc for the method `authenticated`, which should answer your question : http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#authenticated-instance_method